# configure osxmotion library and license manager in Canon Juma(STM32F401)

Tags: texas-instruments

I am trying to configure osxmotion library in Juma Canon. I was able to successfully import motionar,motionfx,motioncp,motiongr library in the project but was unable to properly execute the license manager. I am attaching the video link- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v35_pLUQQlU.

Comment: Please do not post a video of the code. This cannot be searched, cannot be copied for testing, and impede accessibility.
Instead, include relevant code as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Sir, its a embed c code. It has four major files with more than 2000 LOC and the inter dependencies are too high that couldn't be explained using few lines of text only. This is the reason I created the video for better explanation.@Meyer

Comment: People should not need to go to an external video website in order to understand the problem though, Nitish. Is there a way you can compress the problem into the question itself?

Comment: Sir, I am sorry but if I compressed the problem in form of text then it wouldn't be feasible for the people to understand the exact problem. Apologies. @halfer